# scons environment configuration from Linux to Windows

Tags: scons

I have a scons scrip that specifies Boost libraries. This script is specific to Linux.

```
env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-lboost_program_options', '-lboost_filesystem', '-lboost_system'])
env.Append(CXXFLAGS=['-std=c++17', '-lboost_program_options',  '-lboost_filesystem', '-lboost_system'])
env.Append(LIBS=['-lboost_program_options',  '-lboost_filesystem', '-lboost_system' ])
```

I want to install the application on a Windows machine and have installed Boost on the Windows machine. But how to modify the scons script to point to Boost? The -std=c++17 is easy since Visual Studio can toggle standard from C/C++ Language in the Project setting. Don't know where to set boost_program_options, boost_filesystem, and boost_system in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Some of this is incorrect for any platform. Here's what would be correct for linux.

```
env.Append(CXXFLAGS=['-std=c++17'])
env.Append(LIBS=['boost_program_options',  'boost_filesystem', 'boost_system' ])
```

Here's what would be correct for windows:

env.Append(CXXFLAGS=['/std:c++17'])
env.Append(LIBS=['boost_program_options',  'boost_filesystem', 'boost_system' ])

You should not specify -lLIBRARY_NAME anywhere for SCons.
Just the LIBRARY_NAME in LIBS.

You'll need to specify LIBPATH to point to the libraries on windows. (Or perhaps env['ENV']['PATH'] as well)

Comment: Why did you say -lboost_program_options etc are incorrect for any platform? I see programs use this way in scons and worked.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of SCons. You list the library names in LIBS. Please take a read of the users guide or the manpage if you'd like to learn more.  SCons will automatically add the linking commands to the linker command line using the LIBS list. It will do the correct thing for the compiler/linker being used.  Arguments such as "-lLIBRARY_NAME" only work for linkers which use the "-l" flag to link against libraries. MSVC does not..

Comment: See: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idp140637538424320

Comment: The -ILIBRARY_NAME stuff were from Linux specific script, from the OP. (S)He was asking the MSVC counterpart. But I think you explained it well now

Comment: Thanks, now I know how to put that in Windows. I experimented a bit on Windows before I see the answer. It seems Windows had already included all Boost library (assuming either from binary or compiled libraries) so no need to included individual ones. BTW, I was trying to migrate an AI model Maestro to Windows. The scons script is from there.

Comment: @visitor99999 - Unfortunately many SCons build systems "in the wild" were built without reading the SCons docs or asking for help from the community and end up with many issues like the one you've asked about. Glad I was able to help!

Comment: Also if the answer above is correct for you, please mark it as the solution/answer for your question.